# CSRF Token in CakePHP when doing a CURL Post request

Tags: php, curl, post, cakephp, csrf

I'm pretty new to CakePHP and I've been trying to figure out this issue for a while now.

What is happening is the following:

I'm basically trying to get results using php POST CURL from a different IP/domain to the Cake application. However every time I do this I keep getting an error in the CakePHP application log "Missing CSRF Token Cookie".

I've looked through the documentation and various posts online but I still do not fully understand this.

I'm hoping someone here can give me a better explanation on what this error means. How do I pass the CSRF Token when making a CURL connection with php? More importantly how do I get the Cake application CSRF Token?

Sorry if this sounds like a stupid question, but I am truly lost and don't know where else to look. I appreciate your help in advance.

EDIT 1
We are attempting to add data into the system, there is no issue when we do a GET request, that one is working well. The issue comes from doing a POST request.

EDIT 2
I'm adding my AppController code and my other controller that is doing all the functions. What i'm trying to do is to just get the POST to work, so i can implement functions to add or edit data stored in the DB.

AppController.php

```
namespace App\Controller;

use Cake\Controller\Controller;
use Cake\Event\Event;

class AppController extends Controller
{
    public function initialize()
    {
        parent::initialize();
        $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler', [
            'enableBeforeRedirect' => false,
        ]);
        $this->loadComponent('Flash');
    }
}
```

WebservicesController.php

```
namespace App\Controller;
use Cake\Event\Event;

class WebservicesController extends AppController{
  protected   $responseBody   =   [];

  public function beforeRender(Event $event){
    foreach($this->responseBody as $responseKey=>$response){

       $this->set($responseKey, $response);
    }
    $this->set('_serialize', array_keys($this->responseBody));

  }

  public function initialize(){
    parent::initialize();
    $this->RequestHandler->renderAs($this, 'json');
  }

  public function index(){
    ///getting data 
    $this->request->allowMethod(['get']);
    $id = $this->request->getQuery("id");
    $this->responseBody["statusCode"] = 200;
    $this->responseBody['statusDescription'] = "";
    $this->responseBody['data'] = array();
  }

  public function getOneItem(){
    $this->request->allowMethod(['post']);

    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
      //Add/Edit Data in here.
      $id = $this->request->getQuery("id");
      $this->responseBody["statusCode"] = 200;
      $this->responseBody['statusDescription'] = "";
      $this->responseBody['data'] = array();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It might be worth explaining what the requested endpoint in your app actually does. If you just want to read data, then there's no need to issue a non-GET request (where the CSRF token will be checked) in the first place.

Comment: @ndm I've updated my original post, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

CSRF is a mechanism that protects from HTML form tampering by generating a token and some hidden fields. With curl, you have no HTML form, so no token generated, so that kind of control is just not possible. You got to disable that security.

A simple answer maybe : disable CSRF security in appController.php.

```
if (!$this->request->is('ajax')) {
    $this->loadComponent('Security');
    $this->loadComponent('Csrf');
}
```

You can do it inconditionnaly, of course, an re-enable it in every other controller, in the initialize() function. But you wouldn't want to do that.

A way better solution is to disable Security **AND** CSRF in a specific controller, for a specific action, as mentionned in the documentation, in two distinct places :

1. https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/csrf.html#disabling-the-csrf-component-for-specific-actions
2. https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/security.html#disabling-security-component-for-specific-actions

In my situation (and yours) i want to add something by POST with curl.

So these lines in the controller works:

```
public function beforeFilter(Event $event)
{
    $this->Security->setConfig('unlockedActions', ['add']);
    $this->getEventManager()->off($this->Csrf);
}
```

Curl command (here i post a file and some id, but that could be anything):

```
 curl -k -X POST --cookie CAKEPHP=xxxx -F "file=@index.jpeg" -F fk_id=1 https://hostname/cake/files.json
```

And the result is a json representation of the object.

```
{
    "file": {
        "fk_id": 1,
        "file": {
            "tmp_name": "\/tmp\/phpBUaHon",
            "error": 0,
            "name": "index.jpeg",
            "type": "image\/jpeg",
            "size": 7861
        },
        "created": "2018-08-22T06:08:06+00:00",
        "modified": "2018-08-22T06:08:06+00:00",
        "id": 14
    }
}
```

Comment: Disabling Security can *never* be an acceptable solution. Instead, include the CSRF token as part of the Curl Post data, and modify the server side to look for that token in whatever manner you decided to implement it. E.g., your JSON format could be, `{ "csrf": TOKEN, "data": ALL THE REAL DATA }`